# Android Studio is giving errors and warnings after enabling view binding. How to fix?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-viewbinding

I am getting errors after i enabled view binding in my project.

I have tried resyncing the project, invalidating cache.
My app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.learning.aboutme"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    viewBinding.enabled = true

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

My project gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
     repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()

     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

          // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
          // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }
}

allprojects {
     repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()

     }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My activity main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text"
        style="@style/name_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nickname_edit"
        style="@style/name_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name_it_what_is_your_nickname"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/done" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nickname_text"
        style="@style/name_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star_Image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/yellow_star"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="@dimen/spacing_multiplier"
            android:text="@string/bio"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here the android studio gives a warning on `android:contentDescription`,`textAlignment`, `lineSpacingMultiplier`, `text` etc

Here is my main activity.kt file:

```kotlin
package com.learning.aboutme

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import com.learning.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    private fun addNickname(view: View) {

    }
}
```

Here android studio says: Cannot access `android.viewbinding.ViewBinding` which is a supertype of `com.learning.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding`. On `ActivityMainBinding.inflate()`

I tried creating a new project and moving my files there but the same errors ( Tried moving `activity_main.xml` and the same errors.

How to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I mistook your question.

Comment: Give your root view some id and rebuild

Comment: but how to solve `Here the android studio gives a warning on android:contentDescription,textAlignment, lineSpacingMultiplier, text etc`?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 44):

For me the error went away when I added

```
implementation 'com.android.databinding:viewbinding:4.0.1'
```

to the `build.gradle` file.

This dependency contains the class `android.viewbinding.ViewBinding` which AndroidStudio could not access.

Comment: We use `compile` instead of `implementation` so the dependency won't be included in the APK since this issue only appears in Android Studio and not while running the app.

Comment: Rather `compileOnly` in modern Gradle. As docs [source](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies) state:
"Dependencies whose API is required at compile time but whose implementation is to be provided by a consuming library, application or runtime environment."

Comment: In our project we use androidX dependency but I still see the error in android studio the it require `android.viewbinding.ViewBinding` class. This is kind of AS glitch. Hope it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 12):

In my case the following steps (clearing of cache) did help:

Step 1 : open Terminal and goto your project path in terminal.
Step 2 : *Optional* Hit this command `git clean -xfd` or safe variant `git clean`.  **Be careful with `-xfd` this as this removes untracked files and `.gitignore files`**
Step 3 : Goto : File -> Invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: Hey! this worked

Comment: this actually solved it for me too, ty :)

Comment: BE CAREFUL WITH THIS COMMAND - it will delete ANY file that is referenced in gitignore. if you have some untracked security files or keys or whatever that you don't push but have in your project, they will be deleted. people should stop posting commands and not explaining what they do

Comment: @Trevor Sorry that this messed up your project, If you use IDEA you can use Local history to restore you project state https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html

Answer (score 11):

Facing same issue exact error yesterday. Solution work for me is

- Step 1- Remove .Idea Folder
- Step 2- Close android studio
- Step 3- Reopen android studio with same project path (This will genarate new
  .Idea folder)

and Error is gone

Making sure

1. android.useAndroidX=true.  inside gradle.properties file
2. inside app build.gradle

> ```
>  buildFeatures {
>        viewBinding true
>  }
> ```

3. Always Use folder structure with small case latter only class name is allowed to be Uppercase
4. If you are using any Copyright-Comment at top of xml or Layout tag without variable tag or we can say without any data then remove that and try to clean/rebuild project

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution from here: https://cdmana.com/2021/05/20210511224308742x.html . Just add at `gradle.properties`

```html
//...
android.enableD8=true
android.injected.testOnly=false
```

I hope it will solving your problem

Comment: "The option 'android.enableD8' is deprecated."

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with that error

```
android.viewbinding.ViewBinding which is a supertype of com.learning.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding. On ActivityMainBinding.inflate()
```

What I did and solved it was erasing from the build.grade module

```
viewBinding{
   enabled = true
}
```

And Sync it, after re added the erased code from the module and sync again and voila! That solved it for me. Thanks for all other responses tho

Answer (score 1):

I faced this exact error today when I used viewBinding in my fragment so what helped was

1. Clean and Rebuild project.
2. Invalidate caches and restart.

Somehow the Invalidate caches and restart to be specific solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Error Solved for me By:
Adding below line in the gradle.properties(Project Propoerties) file:

android.useAndroidX=true

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

add "multiDexEnabled true" in gradle file like below

```
android {
compileSdk 30

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.test"
    minSdk 19
    targetSdk 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

i adding dependencies in build.gradle

- implementation 'com.android.databinding:viewbinding:4.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I fix it by doing the steps below:

1- go to build.gradle file and remove
 `buildFeatures { viewBinding = true }`
if you already put it there
2-synch
3-Clean and Rebuild the project.
4-put viewBinding back again
 `buildFeatures { viewBinding = true}`
5-synch again

Answer (score 0):

For me the error went away when I added

`implementation 'com.android.databinding:viewbinding:7.3.1'`
to the build.gradle file.

This dependency contains `android.viewbinding.ViewBinding` which android studio may not be able to access without this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

To me this happened because I had my layout wrapped into `<layout>` tag. This tag is only needed if you use data binding and causes issues when used with view binding alone.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what worked for me:

I initially had the build.gradle(Module: App_name.app) file opened in Android Studio.

Then I opened the "Project Structure" window ...
There, at the left pane, I opened the "suggestions" tab.

Several Suggestions for updating things were there, which I selected and pressed OK , after which they started getting updated from internet, and after that, did Gradle sync, and all Errors were gone in the MainActivity.kt file.