# Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies with gradle version 7.0.1

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, data-binding, android-viewbinding

I Stuck with the problem. I have upgrade project grade to 7.0.1 and Kotlin 1.5.30. Before upgrading everything was working fine. But after upgrading, I am start getting the following error for each project. Even, I have tried to create new project also. There is also same issue I am facing. Please check the below image.
[image]

Below, I am writing all the files of my project. Which is responsible for data binding and view binding.

**Project base build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.30'
  repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Application based build.gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "colour.moon"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
}
```

**settings.gradle file** Here this file automatically containing the given code. I though to put it here for easy understanding

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

This is main file, Which is producing the error. Please check it carefully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="colour.moon.MainVM" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

When, I am converting my view to `layout` then the above error is coming. Please let me know, How to solved it? And If we need to remove layout then how to use data binding in the XML file!

I will be very thankful for your answer on it!

Comment: This solution is work for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71036661/4741746